# Objective C: How to add "plus" button in cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

Can anyone advise me on how I can add a "plus" button in a UITableView Cell like what you see in the screen shot below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way: get an image of the plus, set it for the `cell.imageView.image`.

Comment: I prefer this method because it doesn't create an offset on the left side of the tableview.

Comment: If you are using a grouped table you can simply call this tableview method to avoid indentation:

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return NO;

}

Answer (score 31):

You can also put the table view into editing mode, implement `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` (which puts a green circle with a plus sign).

For example...

```
- (IBAction)editButtonPressed
{
    //toggle editing on/off...
    [tableView setEditing:(!tableView.editing) animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
               //gives green circle with +
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
               //or UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone
}
```

When the green button is pressed, the table view will call `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        //handle insert...
    }
    else
    {
        //handle delete...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great!!!. Thanks anna. I was thinking one would have t write something custom to get this. Cool!!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your cell by getting the `contentView` property of your `UITableViewCell` and adding the `UIImage` of the plus button as a subview.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a built-in control. It's probably a custom-style UIButton with that image in its .image property.